# Hadoop conf to determine num map tasks

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a job, like all my Hadoop jobs, it seems to have a total of 2 map tasks when running from what I can see in the Hadoop interface. However, this means it is loading so much data that I get a Java Heap Space error.

I've tried setting many different conf properties in my Hadoop cluster to make the job split into more tasks but nothing seems to have any effect.

I have tried setting `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`, `mapred.max.split.size`, `dfs.block.size` but none seem to have any effect.

I'm using 0.20.2-cdh3u6, and trying to run a job using cascading.jdbc - the job is failing on reading data from the database. I think this issue can be resolved by increasing the number of splits but can't work out how to do that!

Please help! Going crazy!

```
2013-07-23 09:12:15,747 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:59)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1477)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2936)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:477)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2631)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1800)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2221)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
        at cascading.jdbc.db.DBInputFormat$DBRecordReader.<init>(DBInputFormat.java:97)
        at cascading.jdbc.db.DBInputFormat.getRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:376)
        at cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputFormat$1.operate(MultiInputFormat.java:282)
        at cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputFormat$1.operate(MultiInputFormat.java:277)
        at cascading.util.Util.retry(Util.java:624)
        at cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputFormat.getRecordReader(MultiInputFormat.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:324)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code of what you are doing inside your map() function?

Comment: Can you describe the source for the data? Are you pulling from a database, or from the filesystem? If the latter, what is the file type?

Comment: I'm pulling from a database table, one Tap source is 637,018 rows, the other is 116,198 rows. The job fails before it reaches any cascading functions I've written myself. I'll add the exception to my question.

Comment: can you try adding `-Xmx64m` to `mapred.child.java.opts` property in `mapred-site.xml` and retry your job (this is an obviously too small value)

Comment: Thanks Brugere, I looked up that property and after trying to set it to 1024m I found my job ran fine. I'll find a way to set this programmatically for jobs that I know are going to need to read in lots of data.

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My job was reading in data from a table where 1,000 rows equates to about 1MB. This particular job was trying to read in 753,216 urls. Turns out the Java heap space of each task process is capped at 200MB. As Brugere pointed out in the comments on my question, I can set the `mapred.child.java.opts` property in `mapred-site.xml` which controls heap space (http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module7.html).

I found I also had to set `<final>true</final>` for this property in my config file else the value was reset to 200MB (is it possible it's reset somewhere in the code? perhaps in cascading.jdbc?).

I'll be looking at setting this heap space property in my code when setting up a job when I detect that it will require a larger amount of heap space, leaving the general Hadoop config setup to use the default 200MB.

Comment: wrt the final parameter - I've just seen in the logs on a worker node

2013-07-24 10:48:24,432 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: /var/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/tomcat/jobcache/job_201307240946_0003/job.xml:a attempt to override final parameter: mapred.child.java.opts;  Ignoring.

Comment: I do not know if its same in cascading but in lingual (cascading extension) there is an hadoop-override file with some settings. You could try to edit some jar or exec files.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the settings of memory management like `io.sort.mb` or `mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb` because heap space errors are generally due to an allocation problem and not to map number.

If you want to force your map number you have to consider that some values are used prior to others. For instance  `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` if small will generate a huge amount of taks even if you set `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` to a small value.

The `dfs.block.size` has impact on generated map number only if it is greater than the `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`